# Javafx: button handler in a button handler

Tags: java, button, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

```
Button a=new Button();
...
a.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
             Button []b=new Button();
         ...
        }
    });
```

After clicking the button a, the other buttons b will show up. I want to make an event handler for the buttons b. What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's the problem with doing exactly what you want and just creating event handlers for the buttons b?

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the attempt to assign a `Button` instance to a `Button[]` array, which the compiler will tell you in the message for the compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called adding a Node(button) dynamically. You can practice with this approach.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication91 extends Application
{
    int idControl = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {        
        VBox root = new VBox();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Add New Button");
        btn.setId("Button " + idControl);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                idControl++;
                Button tempButton = new Button();
                tempButton.setText("Button " + idControl);
                tempButton.setId("Button " + idControl);
                tempButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You clicked: " + ((Button)event2.getSource()).getId());
                    }                
                });

                root.getChildren().add(tempButton);                
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

This app creates a button on start up. If you click the button it creates a new button. Each new button, when clicked, shows the id of the button being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to have a button handler inside a button handler, if the `Button b` shows up only after clicking `Button a`, you could add another `Button b` handler (outside `Button a` handler), `Button b` cannot not fire a click event if its not visible